# Dumping gcov data at runtime

Tags: c, code-coverage, gcov

I'm using gcov to collect code coverage data for a C project I'm working on. I understand that gcov dumps the code coverage data once the program exits after completion. How do I collect gcov data for long running processes. (say, my program is the kernel of an operating system which runs in a server that never shuts down - and I need to collect code coverage data for it). Is there any way to make gcov dump code coverage data periodically (say, every 1 hour) or upon certain event - how can I trigger gcov dump code coverage data (rather than waiting for gcov to do it after the program terminates)?

Answer (score 5):

Call `__gcov_flush()` periodically.

This can be done by associating a [signal handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void __gcov_flush();

static void catch_function(int signal) {
   __gcov_flush();
}

int main(void) {
    if (signal(SIGINT, catch_function) == SIG_ERR) {
        fputs("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while(1);
}
```

Compile regularly: `gcc sig.c -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs`
Then toggle (periodic) update by `kill -2 process_id`