# Dumping gcov data in case of program crashes

Tags: c, gcov

I'm using gcov to collect code coverage data for a C project. How do I collect gcov data for long running processes because the program  might crash losing all code coverage data. Is there any way to make gcov dump code coverage data periodically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dumping gcov data at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977285/dumping-gcov-data-at-runtime)